# How do you get the table cells selected with Ctrl key in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

In Firefox, when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click table cells, you add/remove them to a non-contiguous selection. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+drag creates a contiguous selection.

[image]

How do you find out in DOM/jQuery etc. whether a cell is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getSelectedElements() {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const selectedElements = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; i++) {
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(i);

        selectedElements.push(range.startContainer.childNodes[range.startOffset]);
    }

    return selectedElements;
}
```